# PostGIS st_intersection returns only the lines that are inside the polygon

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, sql

I have two polygons called 1, 2.
I have a linestring that crosses the two polygons but does not remain only inside them.

[image]

What I'm trying to do:

Find the linestring that is from A to D in the case of polygon 1 and
Find the line that is from E to H in the case of polygon number 2

So from that big linstring I only need these two linstrings and their size in KM

Now as I tried to do:

```
def geospatial_intersection(pg_conn, geom_A, geom_B):
   
    sql1 = """SELECT st_intersection('%s' , '%s') as rez""" % (geom_A, geom_B)
    #print(sql1)
    c1 = pg_conn.cursor()
    c1.execute(sql1)
    row1 = c1.fetchall() 
    
    return row1[0][0]
```

It's just that it only returns these to me:
MULTILINESTRING with segments A-B and C-D in the case of polygon 1 and
MULTILINESTRING with segments E-F and G-H in the case of polygon 2

I miss polygon 1 segment B-C and polygon 2 segment F-G ...

```
    SELECT
  ply.ogc_fid AS pid, 
  lns.ogc_fid AS lid,
  ST_LineSubstring(lns.wkb_geometry, frc.st, frc.ed) AS geom
FROM
  limite_pug_bacau AS ply
  JOIN
  traseu AS lns ON ST_Intersects(ply.wkb_geometry, lns.wkb_geometry),
  LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_Intersection(ply.wkb_geometry, lns.wkb_geometry) AS geom
  ) AS its,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_MakeLine(dmp.geom ORDER BY dmp.path) AS geom
    FROM
      ST_DumpPoints(its.geom) AS dmp
  ) AS ln,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_LineLocatePoint(lns.wkb_geometry, ST_StartPoint(ln.geom)) AS st,
      ST_LineLocatePoint(lns.wkb_geometry, ST_EndPoint(ln.geom)) AS ed
  ) AS frc
;
```

I tried as geozelot said but it returns this error to me:

```
ERROR:  line_locate_point: 1st arg isn't a line
   SQL state: XX000
```

The two tables in which the geometries are located are not linked with each other

Comment: In SQL terms, the intersection of a line and a polygon is the parts of the line within the polygon, so your result is correct.  If your want the parts of the line which are *outside* the polygon, you need a different query (using `ST_Difference` to erase the parts of the line within the polygons).

Comment: If you split the linestring at intersections the desired result contains the parts that are inside any polygon, plus the parts with both start point and end point touching the boundary of the same polygon. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes. This is corect! @user30184

Comment: Then for finding the missing pieces you could use  https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html,  https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html, https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html, and maybe https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html but https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html will do as well. There will be a practical problem because it is difficult to make artificially created points to touch exactly a line when used in another function so it may be necessary to use ST_Buffer for start/endpoints, or to use https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html instead ST_Touches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, simple, but a little wordy in SQL - still fast:

*Edited to use OPs relation/column names.*

```
SELECT
  ply.ogc_fid AS pid, 
  lns.ogc_fid AS lid,
  ST_LineSubstring(lns.wkb_geometry, frc.st, frc.ed) AS geom
FROM
  limite_pug_bacau AS ply
  JOIN
  traseu AS lns ON ST_Intersects(ply.wkb_geometry, lns.wkb_geometry),
  LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_Intersection(ply.wkb_geometry, lns.wkb_geometry) AS geom
  ) AS its,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_MakeLine(dmp.geom ORDER BY dmp.path) AS geom
    FROM
      ST_DumpPoints(its.geom) AS dmp
  ) AS ln,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_LineLocatePoint(ST_LineMerge(lns.wkb_geometry), ST_StartPoint(ln.geom)) AS st,
      ST_LineLocatePoint(ST_LineMerge(lns.wkb_geometry), ST_EndPoint(ln.geom)) AS ed
  ) AS frc
;
```

Comment: I edited the question and asked the problem I encountered with your version @geozelot. Can we transcribe a query because we don't need to link the tables together?

Comment: @CoderCoder42 the `FROM` clause specifies *tables* (or set rerurning expressions), nor columns I assume `wkb_geometry` is the column name in both tables? See my update.

Comment: Yes its the geometry column name its the both tables

Comment: @CoderCoder42 as I said, run the updated query above.

Comment: All error returns to me:

ERROR: line_locate_point: 1st arg isn't a line
SQL state: XX000

I tried the query given by you see in my question.

Comment: @CoderCoder42 and _are_ your `traseu.wkb_geometry`s `LINESTRING`s?

Comment: Mixed value MULTILINESTRING and LINESTRING uplied this ST_LineMerge and resolv....

Comment: Thank you! @geozelot